# Given a "polyline", find a value x for the polyline that passes through the points (a, b)

Tags: geometry

Here's the description of the problem:

There is a polyline going through points (0, 0) – (x, x) – (2x, 0) – (3x, x) – (4x, 0) – ... - (2kx, 0) – (2kx + x, x) – ....

We know that the polyline passes through the point (a, b). Find minimum positive value x such that it is true or determine that there is no such x.

Link to problem statement:
http://codeforces.com/contest/579/problem/C

[image: (a, b) = (3, 1)]

[image: (a, b) = (4, 1)]

I can sort of see how if b > a then there is no solution. But if a >= b, how do I approach this problem? I think that it's an upwards slope the starting point in the x axis will be at a/2*x and downwards slope the start will be at x + 2*x. Maybe I am approaching this the wrong way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have two possibilities:

1) $a=2nx+b$, whence: $x=(a-b)/(2n)$;

2) $a=2nx-b$, whence: $x=(a+b)/(2n)$;

where $n$ is some non-negative integer.
To have the minimum $x$ we must find the maximum possible $n$.

From the condition $x\ge b$ one can constrain $n$ in both cases and find $x$.